# org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot instantiate class test.AddCustomerTest

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to run this code as maven project in eclipse but I am getting error when I am trying to run the tests as TestNG.
here is my all code:

### **util(package)** ExcelReader .java

```
package util;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReader {

    //Global Variables
    public String path;
    public FileInputStream fis = null;
    private XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    private XSSFSheet sheet = null;
    private XSSFRow row = null;
    private XSSFCell cell = null;

    // Constructor to initialize variables
    public ExcelReader(String path) {
    this.path = path;
    try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    // Method to call the value
    public String getCellData(String sheetName, String colName, int rowNum) {
    // For Sheet
    int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
    int col_Num = 0;
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);

    // For Row
    row = sheet.getRow(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
    if (row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName.trim())) {
    col_Num = i;
    }
    }

    // For Column
    row = sheet.getRow(rowNum - 1);
    cell = row.getCell(col_Num);
    return cell.getStringCellValue();
    }
    
}
```

### **src/test** AddCustomerTest

```
package test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import page.AddCustomersPage;
import page.DashboardPage;
import page.LoginPage;
import util.BrowserFactory;
import util.ExcelReader;

public class AddCustomerTest {

    WebDriver driver;

    ExcelReader exlread = new ExcelReader("TestData\\Test.xlsx");
    String userName = exlread.getCellData("LoginInfo", "UserName", 2);
    String password = exlread.getCellData("LoginInfo", "Password", 2);
    String fullname = exlread.getCellData("AddContactInfo", "FullName", 2);
    String companyName = exlread.getCellData("AddContactInfo", "CompanyName", 2);
    String email = exlread.getCellData("AddContactInfo", "Email", 2);
    String phoneNum = exlread.getCellData("AddContactInfo", "Phone", 2);
    String addresss = exlread.getCellData("AddContactInfo", "Address", 2);
    String country = exlread.getCellData("AddContactInfo", "Country", 2);
    String city = exlread.getCellData("AddContactInfo", "City", 2);
    String state = exlread.getCellData("AddContactInfo", "State", 2);
    String zip = exlread.getCellData("AddContactInfo", "Zip", 2);

    @Test
    public void validUserShouldBeAbleToAddCustomer() {

        driver = BrowserFactory.init();

        LoginPage loginpage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
        loginpage.enterUserName("demo@techfios.com");
        loginpage.enterPassword("abc123");
        loginpage.clickSignInButton();

        DashboardPage dashboardpage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, DashboardPage.class);
        dashboardpage.validateDashboardPage();

        AddCustomersPage addcustomer = PageFactory.initElements(driver, AddCustomersPage.class);
        addcustomer.clickOnCustomerButton();
        addcustomer.clickOnADDCustomerButton();
        addcustomer.enterFullName(fullname);
        addcustomer.enterCompanyName("companyName");
        addcustomer.enterEmail("email");
        addcustomer.EnterPhoneNumber("phoneNum");
        addcustomer.EnterAddress("addresss");
        addcustomer.EnterCountry(country);
        addcustomer.EnterCity("city");
        addcustomer.EnterCountry(state);
        addcustomer.EnterCountry(zip);
        addcustomer.clickSaveButton();
        addcustomer.clickListCustomerButton();

        // BrowserFactory.tearDown();

    }

}
```

### **Error**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.3.0
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class test.AddCustomerTest
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor(InstanceCreator.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstanceUsingObjectFactory(InstanceCreator.java:113)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstance(InstanceCreator.java:79)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:109)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:167)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:102)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:82)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:74)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:39)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:457)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:336)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:220)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng.ITestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(ITestRunnerFactory.java:55)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:676)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:178)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1306)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1282)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1131)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:23)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (-1) is out of range (0..1)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.validateSheetIndex(XSSFWorkbook.java:1453)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.getSheetAt(XSSFWorkbook.java:1129)
    at util.ExcelReader.getCellData(ExcelReader.java:38)
    at test.AddCustomerTest.<init>(AddCustomerTest.java:18)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Please make sure you are providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (-1) is out of range (0..1)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.validateSheetIndex(XSSFWorkbook.java:1453)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.getSheetAt(XSSFWorkbook.java:1129)
    at util.ExcelReader.getCellData(ExcelReader.java:38)
    at test.AddCustomerTest.<init>(AddCustomerTest.java:18)
    ... 32 more
```

Which means that when your class is being statically initialized an the line `AddCustomerTest.java:18`. It goes to your `ExcelReader` clsass that tries to obtain index of sheet by its name but it returns `-1` which means (if you look at [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#getSheetIndex-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet-)) that **it fails to find the sheet with given name `LoginInfo`**.